# How to find Kubernetes pod that's handling the request

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running 2 pods and a service with Type: NodePort, to load balance the requests between pods. I want to know when I send a request to the service, which pod the request is forwarded to. Is there a way to find this, because looking at the response, it looks like all the requests are handled by same pod.

Answer (score 1):

A kubernetes `Service` will load-balance using WRR by default. When you create a Service, `iptables` rules will be generated in the node.

To be sure, ssh into the node and run `iptables-save|less`. Search for the name of the service. In the example below, a Service `microbot` load balances the `microbot` deployment with 3 replicas. There should be 2 entries in your case since you have just 2 pods.

```
-A KUBE-SVC-LX5ZXALLN4UQ7ZFL -m comment --comment "default/microbot:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33332999982 -j KUBE-SEP-OZCDYTQTC3KQGJK5
-A KUBE-SVC-LX5ZXALLN4UQ7ZFL -m comment --comment "default/microbot:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-SKIRAXBCCQB5R4MV
-A KUBE-SVC-LX5ZXALLN4UQ7ZFL -m comment --comment "default/microbot:" -j KUBE-SEP-SPMPNZCOIJIRSNNQ
```

If the `iptables` output doesn't look like the above, it's likely that your Service is not configured properly. Like what [Heidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162149/heidi-schmidt) said, the pods are not associated with the Service.

Comment: I have two pods, mine looks like this `-A KUBE-SVC-RCFZYSCVQORLOLVD -m comment --comment "default/memory-service:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-CXEQ55XIH4PURQSE
-A KUBE-SVC-RCFZYSCVQORLOLVD -m comment --comment "default/memory-service:" -j KUBE-SEP-QL7KI24MTSZRY3Q3`

Comment: The iptables rules look correct and should load balance correctly. Can you make the `memory-service` daemon log each hit? That way you can use `kubectl logs -f` the pod to observe. Alternatively, expose 1 more port in the Deployment and associate it with the Service. Once you do, `kubectl exec` into the pod, install netcat and get it to listen continuously on the extra port. Then run your tests again. That's how I would debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `podIP` from your running pod's yaml file, it will vary for each pod. Refer the screenshot below

[image]

Now you can check the ingress logs which has all incoming requests. Filter the logs by matching this `podIP` value, it will be shown as `serverIp` in logs. Refer the screenshot below

[image]

In this way, you can find which K8s pod handled the request.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because of your context and lack of namespace you can't see the logs.

Try `kubectl get pods -o wide  --all-namespaces | grep <pod>` to get the information of which namespace the pod is in and the node IP address.

Then feed the  and  into the command below to get a running tail of the last 100 lines of the log 
`kubectl --namespace <namespace> logs --tail 100 -f <pod>`

There is also the remote chance that the pod is not associated with the service. To check run `kubectl describe services --namespace <namespace> <service>` and look for the app name in the `Selector:` section

You can also exec into the container and see if the port is accessible or bound on the pod itself. If it isn't listening or answering, most likely it's due to the service not being associated with the application in the namespace.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can look at the application log file, if your using one. if you print anything in stdout, use `kubectl logs <pod>` to see the message.
2. For testing you can include pod hostname in the response.

Comment: Are you logging anything?